# How can I stop my images to resize Bootstrap 4' carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

In my website, people will upload images with different sizes. These images will be displayed in Bootstrap 4' carousel. I need my carousel to always maintain a certain dimension throughout different screen sizes (responsive), and I don't want the images to change it's width nor it's height. I came across different questions regarding the same topic, but none seem to work for me.

```
codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/dByGwj?editors=1100
```

[image: This is what is happening]

[image: This is what I need]

Comment: please upload images in your codepen

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has two solutions either you can set static hight and the full width of the image or you can implement the image cropper of fixed dimensions on upload image.

Comment: Could you comment a bit more on the image cropper / fixed dimensions please? I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: You can use these types of plugins 
Croppie - https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/
jqueryCropper - https://fengyuanchen.github.io/jquery-cropper/
jqueryCropper options - https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#options